# MongoDB Aggregate subfields with individual date ranges

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a schema which is:

```
{
"_id" : "12345678",
"action1" : [
    {
        "date" : "2021-01-15",
        "value" : 20
    },
    {
        "date" : "2021-01-14",
        "value" : 16
    }
],
"action2" : [
    {
        "date" : "2021-01-15",
        "value" : 30
    },
    {
        "date" : "2021-01-14",
        "value" : 10
    }
],
"action3" : [
    {
        "date" : "2021-01-15",
        "value" : 40
    },
    {
        "date" : "2021-01-14",
        "value" : 20
    }
],
"action4" : [
    {
        "date" : "2021-01-15",
        "value" : 60
    },
    {
        "date" : "2021-01-14",
        "value" : 40
    }
]
```

}

Now I want to write an aggregate query to filter out counts within a date range (for last 7 days, or 30 days or 90 days)

so the final sum should look something like the following:

```
{
    _id: "12345678"
    action1 : {
        alltime: number,
        last7Days : number,
        last30Days: number,
        last90Days: number
    },
    action2: {
        alltime: number,
        last7Days : number,
        last30Days: number,
        last90Days: number
    },
    action3: {
        alltime: number,
        last7Days : number,
        last30Days: number,
        last90Days: number
    },
    action4: {
        alltime: number,
        last7Days : number,
        last30Days: number,
        last90Days: number
    },
}
```

I am trying to get the total number of actions using `$project` and `$match` for a particular `_id`

But how can I filter the past7days/30days/90days data

My query looks like the following

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
            $project: {
                alltimeAction1: {$sum: "$action1.value"},
                alltimeAction2: {$sum: "$action2.value"},
                alltimeAction3: {$sum: "$action3.value"},
                alltimeAction4: {$sum: "$action4.value"}
            }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            _id: "12345678"
        }
    }
])
```

is `mapReduce` the only option available?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.test1.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {//Reshape actions, you need this as you have dynamic keys
      data: {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {//Denormalize
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {//Denormalize
    "$unwind": "$data.v"
  },
  {
    "$project": {//Formatting date
      "_id": 1,
      "key": "$data.k",
      "date": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$data.v.date",
            "format":"%Y-%m-%d"
          
        }
      },
      "value": "$data.v.value"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {//Getting the conditions ready
      "7Days": {
        $gte:["$date", new Date(new Date().getTime() - (7*24*3600*1000))]
      },
      "30Days": {
        $gte:["$date", new Date(new Date().getTime() - (30*24*3600*1000))]
      }
    }
  },
  {
      $group:{//Grouping them, you can add few more cases
          "_id": "$key",
                  "7days":{
                      $sum:"$value"
                  },
                  "30days":{
                      $sum:"$value"
                  }
                  
              }
  }
  
])
```

You don't need to do this much complex query if you have flattened schema where actionName can be identified by a constant field name.

Comment: action names are constant names eg: "openAction", "closeAction" etc.
in my above question action1, action2 etc are constant field names

Comment: How many of them are there? What are those? I meant flat structure.

Comment: there are 6 of them, open, close, left, right, scroll, click, but the structure is same as mentioned in the question